# Why does some JS behavior work in development, but not when I push to Heroku?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am trying to create a step form - which triggers/shows some fields when something else is chosen.

Here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/XnPZF/ - of it working (it also works in development).

Just can't figure out why this doesn't work when I push to Heroku.

Here is a [version on Heroku](http://realty-cloud.herokuapp.com/listings/new/).

Login credentials: abc@test.com/test123

The fields that should trigger other fields right below it are Property_Type & Category.

Here is a snippet of some code:

`/views/listings/new.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for @listing, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
      <fieldset>
            <%= f.association :property_type %>

    <div style="display: none;" data-show-for-prop-type="Multi Family">
      <h4>Multi-Family</h4>
      <%= f.input :taxes %>
      <%= f.input :house_families %>
      <%= f.input :house_extensions %>
      <%= f.input :house_stories %>
      <%= f.input :house_units %>
    </div>

    <div style="display: none;" data-show-for-prop-type="Condo">
      <h4>Condo</h4>
      <%= f.input :taxes %>
      <%= f.input :common_charges %>
    </div>
```

The `listings.js` file:

```
$('#listing_property_type_id').on('change', function(){
    var option = $(this).find(':selected');
    $('[data-show-for-prop-type]').hide(); //And maybe reset?
    $('[data-show-for-prop-type='+ option.text() +']').show();
});
```

Comment: do you have a link to you js file on heroku?

Comment: Sure do - http://realty-cloud.herokuapp.com/assets/application-13c2ebfca0c7236d4b9032ca41522241.js - it is a bit verbose and minified, but that is the production one. Btw, it seems to contain everything we need (which is what I specified in my `listings.js`). So not quite sure what's happening.

Comment: Seeing several JS errors on http://realty-cloud.herokuapp.com/listings/new... "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oApi' of undefined". Almost positive that might be the issue.

Comment: The issue is that I get this error in development too - so could it be throwing the production environment off, when it doesn't do the same for the dev environment?

Comment: You are absolutely right...that was the issue. If you add that as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing several JS errors on realty-cloud.herokuapp.com/listings/new... "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oApi' of undefined". Almost positive that might be the issue.

The reason Dev did not have the problem is because in dev, it was separate assets, therefore the error was confined to that one js file with that error. However since the asset pipeline compiles into one, errors stop the rest of it's execution.

Best bet, fix all console errors, or add "undefined" checks to prevent those such "Uncaugh TypeError" errors.